# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol, due to ifstream object

Tags: c++, c++11

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class std::locale::id std::codecvt::id" (__imp_?id@?$codecvt@DDH@std@@2V0locale@2@A)
>
> 1>CAssertLog.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned int __cdecl std::codecvt::_Getcat(class std::locale::facet const * *,class std::locale const *)" (__imp_?_Getcat@?$codecvt@DDH@std@@SAIPAPBVfacet@locale@2@PBV42@@Z)
>
> 1>CAssertLog.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int 
>       __thiscall std::codecvt::unshift(int &,char *,char *,char * &)const " (__imp_?unshift@?$codecvt@DDH@std@@QBEHAAHPAD1AAPAD@Z)
>
> 1>CAssertLog.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall std::codecvt::out(int &,char const *,char const *,char const * &,char *,char *,char * &)const " (__imp_?out@?$codecvt@DDH@std@@QBEHAAHPBD1AAPBDPAD3AAPAD@Z)
>
> 1>CAssertLog.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall std::codecvt::in(int &,char const *,char const *,char const * &,char *,char *,char * &)const " (__imp_?in@?$codecvt@DDH@std@@QBEHAAHPBD1AAPBDPAD3AAPAD@Z)
>
> 1>C:\perforce\sw\apps\gpu\drivers\common\logassert\Release\logassert.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals

**Issue Explanation:**

Now I'm seeing above linking error when I add this source line **"ifstream fin;"** to source file. If I remove this source line then code successfully compiles. I already added supported header files and and namespace for **ifstream** object. Not sure, why I'm seeing this linking error. Searched similar error on **SO** and tried their suggested solutions but those solution didn't work for me. Any idea?

**SAMPLE CODE**

```cpp
//In stdafx.h file below code is there 
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

//In program.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
class A
{
    void B();
    ifstream fin; //now if I make this member static then issue goes away. Can anybody explain?
}
```

Comment: You have to give us the source code - at least some reasonable chunk of it to make sense. It could be lots of things e.g. you are linking static but intended to link dynamic libraries, no mentioning of additional libraries or library path in your property sheet in visual studio, etc. I am pretty sure you are using visual studio.

Comment: What compiler?  What does your invocation command look like?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not linking against the standard library.
Since the error messages show `__declspec`, I'll suppose
a Windows environment, with Visual Studios.  By default, this
should work: go into the properties of the project, then into
Linker: in General, Ignore Import Library should be No, and in
Input, Ignore All Default Libraries should be No, and Ignore
Specific Default Libraries should be empty.  (These are the
defaults.)

Otherwise: this could be due to problems with your installation, e.g. if not all of the files are present.

Comment: Actually, Above settings are already there in the project properties.This didn't help.
I'll explain a little more about the code in the question part.

Comment: @Xdev More interesting would be the command line used to invoke the linker.

Comment: @Xdev With regards to making the member static changing things: that's normal; a static member declaration inside a class is only a declaration, not a definition.  So the compiler doesn't need a complete type, and won't generate an externs that it might need to instantiate a complete type.

Comment: Pasting the linker command line in two parts.
/OUT:"C:\perforce\sw\apps\gpu\drivers\common\logassert\Release\logassert.dll" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\perforce\sw\apps\gpu\drivers\common\logassert\Release\logassert.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "shell32.lib" "Shlwapi.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "engextcpp.lib" "dbgeng.lib" "dbghelp.lib" "DbgEng.Lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /FIXED:NO /IMPLIB:"C:\perforce\sw\apps\gpu\drivers\common\logassert\Release\logassert.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X86

Comment: /OPT:REF /SAFESEH /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"C:\perforce\sw\apps\gpu\drivers\common\logassert\Release\logassert.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Release\logassert.dll.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"..\..\..\..\..\tools\ddk\nt6\6000\lib" /LIBPATH:"..\..\..\..\..\tools\boost\boost-1.38.0\lib" /LIBPATH:"..\..\..\..\..\tools\win32\msvc110beta\VC\lib" /LIBPATH:"..\..\..\..\..\tools\sdk\DbgEng\lib\i386" /TLBID:1

Comment: Can you please elaborate your last comment?

Comment: @Xdev I don't see anything in your flags which could account for it.  None of these options would prevent the linker from including the standard libraries, at least as far as I know.  I wonder if your installation is correct.

Comment: @Xdev Just what I said.  The declaration of a static member in the class is _just_ a declaration; it tells the compiler that there will be a definition somewhere else.  So it doesn't trigger the generation of any code which might require something from the object.  A non-static member, on the other hand, is part of the class itself.

Comment: Got it! 
I found this link related  to definition of ifstream on different version of visual studio compiler. It varies with MS compiler version. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae1k9a9f(v=vs.100).aspx
Actually the project is too old and I have opened it in VS2012

Comment: @Xdev You must have something very old.  Normally, when you load an out of date project on a more recent VS, VS asks if you want to convert it, and if you say yes, does so.